# Can I use firebase for only auth and any other SQL database to store other user data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-management

Basically I am building a social media type app. I want to manage the auth using firebase firestore (as It is easier) and the contents posted by the user in any other SQL database. Like, if the user uploads a image it will be stored in my own database. Is it possible to link firebase with my own database? If yes, then how?

Comment: Hi Mahirul, can you give more details about the kind of linking that you're looking for here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) isn't related in any way to Cloud Firestore. You can authenticate your users with Firebase and save the data in any database you want, even in an SQL database. However, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) has some benefits. So I recommend you check the official docs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Firebase for auth only and link it to your own database.

You'll have to use the Firebase Admin SDK in your backend. Check out the [set up guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).